# Выделяет сразу две ссылки подряд, а не одну (рег.выражение)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как можно сделать, чтобы в match ссылки шли друг за другом отдельно, а не одной вместе?

[Ссылка с примером на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cSfPr3/1/)

```
(<a [a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9="#\s'.,?:><;%$&\/]+\/a>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте знак вопроса после плюса, так квантификатор станет ленивым.

Подробнее см. https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-greedy-and-lazy

```
(<a [a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9="#\s'.,?:><;%$&\/]+?\/a>)
```

Comment: Вы правы. Благодарю